# Making a HoHs from two HoAs in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, multidimensional-array, push

I have gene sequence information for differentially expressed (DE) genes, and transcriptomic sequence data (all expressed genes) contained in two hashes of arrays. Both hashes have a unique gene ID as keys (e.g. 'XLOC_000001').

I've written a programme that loops through the tanscriptomic HoA, using the keys from the DE genes HoA, and thus give me gene sequence for only the DE genes.

The HoAs are initialised as follows:

```
my %hash;
push @{ $hash{ $firstkey[$_] } }, [ $p_value[$_], $q_value[$_], $log_fold_change[$_] ] for 0 .. $#firstkey;

my %hash2;
push @{ $hash2{ $secondkey[$_] } }, [ $transcriptID[$_], $sequence[$_] ] for 0 .. $#secondkey;
```

I then use the keys from the first hash to extract values from the second (the keys for both hashes are the same format)

```
for my $firstkey (sort keys %hash) {
    for my $part (@{ $hash2{$firstkey} }) {
        my ($value3, $value4) = @$part; 
        print $output "$firstkey\n$value4\n";
    }
}
```

This works fine. What I'm trying to do now is to include some additional information from the first HoA (P/Q values, and information on the level of expression change) in the output.
My question is: How can I include values from the first hash in my output? I ideally want to print out:

```
%hash2{$firstkey} => $sequence[$_], $p_value[$_], $q_value[$_], $log_fold_change[$_]
```

I'm confused as to whether I should be pushing the second hash of arrays onto the first (if so how?!) or looping through both hashes at the end?

-------- UPDATE---------

Example of each HoA:

Firstkey:

```
Key 'XLOC_001155' contains the values: [ TCONS_00001774 Scaffold10052 SEchx 0 SEchxdex 3.51656 inf 0.00345 0.803695 ] 
Key 'XLOC_001173' contains the values: [ TCONS_00001795 Scaffold10222 SEchx 26.3355 SEchxdex 70.1758 1.41397 0.0199 0.998513 ] 
Key 'XLOC_001177' contains the values: [ TCONS_00001799 Scaffold10227 SEchx 26.2873 SEchxdex 0 -inf 0.01285 0.998513 ] 
Key 'XLOC_001195' contains the values: [ TCONS_00001826 Scaffold10227 SEchx 0.0580138 SEchxdex 0.688545 3.56908 0.0398 0.998513 ] 
Key 'XLOC_000001' contains the values: [ TCONS_00000001 Scaffold10262 SEchx 0 SEchxdex 2.01554 inf 0.00615 0.998513 ] 
Key 'XLOC_001290' contains the values: [ TCONS_00001955 Scaffold103603 SEchx 0 SEchxdex 0.732931 inf 0.0139 0.998513 ] 
Key 'XLOC_001308' contains the values: [ TCONS_00001973 Scaffold1001 SEchx 0 SEchxdex 1.11927 inf 0.00295 0.763416 ] 
Key 'XLOC_000002' contains the values: [ TCONS_00000002 Scaffold10052 SEchx 0.0923385 SEchxdex 23.4041 7.98561 0.02025 0.998513 ]
```

Secondkey:

```
Key 'XLOC_000001' contains the values: [ TCONS_00000001 ATTACAATAACTAAGGAGGACATAGCTTAATTTGCACTATTTACTTTAGTGCATCTGTTGTAGTAGGACGTACAAGGACTTTATTGCTTCAGATAAAGACATTTTATTGCTTTCAAGGTATTCCTGAGACAATTGATCGTGCACTGCAAGCTCCACTTCTAAGTATAAACCAGAGGATTGCAAAACTGGAAGCAGTTCTTAGTTTGACTGGACAATTGTATCAAGTAGGAGGAAAAATGTTTGCCACTAATGGGGAGCAAGTTGATTTTGAGGCCTCTAAACTGACCTGTGAAAAGGCTGGTGGACGAATTGCTACTCCAAAGAATGAAGCAGAGAACAATGTTGTGCTAAGTATTTTAAAGAAACACAATAAATATGCATACCTAGGTGTTACAG ] 

Key 'XLOC_000002' contains the values: [ TCONS_00000002 GTCACACGGCCAGCATCACGCGTGTCACGCTTTTATCCGGAATGAGACCAACTCCAACTTTTTGTGACTGACTTATTTTTCTTCTAGTATAAAAAAATGTCTCGCAGCCACGAGAGACTTCAACGCCTATAACCACCGGCGTACCTCAAAACAAGCAGATAATACCGCGCTAAGCAGCGTTCGGGTTTATAGGCGGGCATAGCCTCACTTCCGGCAGGCTGCTAGGAAACCAAAGAGACGCGGATTCTGATGTTTTGAGCTGCGAGGGTGAAGCGACTGCAAGGACAACAATGGATTCTGAATACATAAAGCGCTGTTTAGGGAAGTGTTTGTCCGAAGGACTTGCAGAAGTCGCGGAAAAAAGACCGATGGATCCTATTGAGT ]
```

---

Comment: Can you please post a sample of `@firstkey`, `@secondkey`, `@value1`, `@value2` etc.? Also, there is no "array of hashes", only hashes of arrays and arrays of arrays.

Comment: The keys for the first HoA contain a subset of the keys from the second. The second HoA contains gene sequence. I want to include all of the information from the first HoA to the sequence, contained in the 2nd HoA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked it out:

```
for my $firstkey (sort keys %hash) {
    for my $part (@{ $hash2{$firstkey} } ) {
        my ($value3, $value4) = @$part;
        print $output "$firstkey ";
        for my $values (@{$hash{$firstkey} } ) {
            my ($value1, $value2) = @$values;
            print $output "$value1, $value2\n";
        }
            print $output "$value4\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To print all the values where the key is present in both `%hash` and `%hash2`, use a conditional and then dereference the arrayrefs.

```
for my $firstkey (sort keys %hash) {
    if ($hash2{$firstkey}) {
        my @values = (@{ $hash{$firstkey} }, @{ $hash2{$firstkey} });
        #my @values = map @{ $_->{$firstkey} }, \(%hash, %hash2);

        print join("\n", @values), "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: The keys for the first HoA contain a subset of the keys from the second. The second HoA contains gene sequence. I want to include all of the information from the first HoA to the sequence, contained in the 2nd HoA. – Nick 3 hours ago